# Toolbar scrolled when PopupMenu showes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-cardview, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm having a CoordinatorLayout with AppbarLayout which includes Toolbar and TabLayout and included ViewPager showing 3 Fragments that includes RecyclerView of CardView.

The issue is when clicking an ImageView (3 dots) on CardView the PopupMenu shows but the Toolbar is scrolled up.

[this is the design with toolbar showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy4jt.png)

[the issue when clicking then toolbar disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMPPW.png)

This is my container activity xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the card view xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_at"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#616161"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/alarm_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#616161"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/alarm_message"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#616161"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/remaining_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#03A9F4"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/overFlow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the fragment xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TodayFragment">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        tools:context=".TodayFragment">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_today"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you try the answer

Answer (score 10):

replace

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this,view);
```

to

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this,view, Gravity.RIGHT);
```

will help you.

Answer (score 3):

We have the same problem. looking at this post:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211014

It seems that the behaviour is ok, but in your case (like us), you don't want that it happens.

If you read all the post, you will see project members are working on a method to "disable" parent scrolling with popupmenu. Maybe in the future it will be available in support libraries .

We must wait for this...

Answer (score 1):

I used "import android.widget.PopupMenu;" instead "import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;" This library have the same interface for PopupMenu, but have no problem with scrolled up Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

please use

import android.widget.PopupMenu;

instead of

import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;